# Host GitLab in VirtualBox

Tags: github, gitlab, bitnami

I tried the prepared VirtualBox stack from bitnami, which I run in bridged mode, but could not pull/push through SSH, I would get prompted with a password request. I have no idea what kind of password this guy wants from me, since none of them worked and I would always get access denied.

I then disabled passwords in the `sshd` configuration file on the server, since I want to work with keys anyway, defined my own `authorized_keys` and added public keys for a sample user.

I then got the message:

> no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I tried calling the repository through HTTP, but this would not enforce any permissions.

I tried setting up my own Virtual Machine with the installer from GitLab, but despite doing everything from tutorials I can't connect to GitLab from outside the VM.

Why and what kind of password does tortoise gitplink want from me? Why can't I use the keys public keys that are placed in the default location on my Windows, and also in a file authorized_keys on the server I am referring to in the sshd configuration file, why does it tell me that there is no authorization method after I disable passphrases?

Comment: As written, this question is likely to be put on hold. You're either asking several different specific questions (but not including exact error messages, config files, etc.) or one very broad one. Please ask just one question at a time, and be as specific as possible.